# Creating the same event after removing causes 409 error

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm writing an app which adds events from our server to user's Google Calendar using API.
And I encountered a *HTTP 409 Conflict* error following this scenario:

1. Create an event with some explicitly defined ID / [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)
2. Delete the event / [Events: delete](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete)
3. Try to create event with the same ID - get the error.

This scenario can come true when:

1. a user exports events from our server.
2. one of the events (say with ID = 1) will be disabled on our server
3. the user exports again the events - this disabled event will removed from user's Google Calendar / *API call: delete, eventId = 1*
4. the disabled event will be enabled again
5. the user performs export - API insert request will be fired with the same ID = 1 . And error 409 will be raised.  / *API call: insert, eventId = 1*

It seems that an event in fact isn't removed after invoking `delete` API method. 
Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Wild guess: if an attempt is made to add an entry with a scope whose
type and value match another entry already in the access control list, the operation will fail with error code 409 (Conflict).  I would look at ACL make sure the old stuff was deleted as well.

Comment: It turned out that so-called "delete" operation in fact don't delete anything - just hide events and change their status to "cancelled". So such events continue to exist in Google Calendar. As workaround I get deleted entries using "showDeleted" = true as well and then updating them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turned out that the so-called "delete" operation in fact doesn't delete events, just hides them and changes their status to "canceled". So events continue to exist in Google Calendar.
As a workaround I retrieve deleted entries using `"showDeleted" = true` option and update them.