# how to get the ColorID of a Google Calendar Event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to write a script to duplicate events  from one Google Calendar to another, but only the events that are colored in *bold red*.

As it stands now, I can duplicate events between multiple calendars, but I don't know how to get the ColorID from the event, so that only the bold red events are being duplicated.
Is such a thing possible in Javascript of by using Google Script?

I searched for this multiple times in the past days, but can only find answers based on PHP. To be honest,  I can't imagine such a thing NOT possible through javascript of Google Script.

Here is the script I wrote so far:

```
function myFunction() }

    var CalendarSource = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarIDPrimaryCalendar@gmail.com");
    var CalendarDest = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarIDDuplicatedCalendar@group.calendar.google.com");
    var Today = new Date(); //Deze variabele bevat de datum van vandaag
    var HalfYear = new Date(new Date(Today).setMonth(Today.getMonth() + 6));//Deze variabele bevat dat datum van vandaag + 6 maanden
    var EventToCopy = CalendarSource.getEvents(Today, HalfYear); //Deze variabele bevat alle Calendar Events voor het aankomende half jaar
```

`// Nieuwe events aanmaken.    

   for (var i in EventToCopy){
      var newEvent = CalendarDest.createEvent(EventToCopy[i].getTitle(), EventToCopy[i].getStartTime(), EventToCopy[i].getEndTime());
  }

}`

What I want is to add an if statement (or something), which checks that only the events which have got ColorID 11 are going to be duplicated.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in Advance,

Jackuss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of searching, reading, trying and hitting my head against a wall because of was frustrated, I finally created a script that does the task I want :). You can find it below. You are free to use it anyway you want, just acknowledge my work (and my headaches ;) ) by not changing the first comment. I would also love to hear from you when you used it.

```
 /* ===========================================
    =============== Created by: ===============
    ============== Jack Reinieren =============
    ========== Date: 29 Juli 2016 =============
    ===========================================
 */

// declare variables
var PriCalendar = "PrimaryCalendar@gmail.com"; //name of primary calendar
var SecCalendar = "*********@group.calendar.google.com"; //name of secondary calendar
var CalendarSource = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(PriCalendar); //variable to store the PriCalendar in
var CalendarDest = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(SecCalendar);//variable to store the SecCalendar in
var Today = new Date(); //todays date
var HalfYear = new Date(new Date(Today).setMonth(Today.getMonth() + 6)); //todays date + 6 months
var Events = Calendar.Events.list(PriCalendar, {timeMin:Today.toISOString(), timeMax:HalfYear.toISOString()}).items; 
// The above creates a list of events with the start date of today and the end date 6 months ahead in time.

//Loop to check if there are events with colored in red if so, then copy to the Secondary Calendar
for (var i in Events){ 
  /* Check if status of events is 'confirmed'  AND the colorId of the event is "11" 
(which means "red", check the colorchart in https://eduardopereira.pt/2012/06/google-calendar-api-v3-set-color-color-chart/) 
*/
if (Events[i].status == "confirmed" && Events[i].colorId == "11"){

  /*Check whether an event already exists, 
this is because Google Calendar doesn't really delete events, when you press delete. Instead the event gets the status "cancelled". 
More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542721/creating-the-same-event-after-removing-causes-409-error
*/  
  try {
  var newEvent = Calendar.Events.insert(Events[i], SecCalendar);
  }
  catch (e){
    // I don't do anything with the errors I encounter, because for what I want, this is not really necessary.
    // You can put in anything you want of course :)
           }
       }
   }
```

Here are the clickable links which are also stated in the comments of the code:

- https://eduardopereira.pt/2012/06/google-calendar-api-v3-set-color-color-chart/  for the Color chart and ColorID's.
- [Creating the same event after removing causes 409 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542721/creating-the-same-event-after-removing-causes-409-error) For the "EventID already exists error".

As I said before, I would love to hear from you if you used (portions) of this code.

With kind regards.

Jack

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [documentation of Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors), it explain here the basic explanation on how the color works on Calendar API, you can also check here the description of the different property name here.

The [`colors.get`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get) also gives you different example code.

Now, for the javascript or apps Script code that you want, I think this sample code from [Calendar Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#creating_events) can give you an idea on how to use `colorId`

```
function createEvent() {
var calendarId = 'primary';
var start = getRelativeDate(1, 12);
var end = getRelativeDate(1, 13);
var event = {
summary: 'Lunch Meeting',
location: 'The Deli',
description: 'To discuss our plans for the presentation next week.',
start: {
dateTime: start.toISOString()
},
end: {
dateTime: end.toISOString()
},
attendees: [
{email: 'alice@example.com'},
{email: 'bob@example.com'}
],
// Red background. Use Calendar.Colors.get() for the full list.
colorId: 11
};
event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

Comment: Thanks KENdi for your quick response :). As far as I can see this code creates an event in a calendar. 
What I want is to search already created events. Events with "colorId: 11" must be duplicated to another calendar. Events with a "colorId" other than 11 _must not_ be duplicated to the second calendar.

Perhaps KENdi, or somebody else, can help me with this? Just to be sure, I _don't_ want the ColorID of the _calendar_, I want the ColorID of the _events_ (the "appointments" or "meetings" so to speak) which are created in a calendar.