# What does 409 error in case of delete in calendar API mean?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, http-status-code-409

I can understand that 409 means duplicate entry in case of addition of events. But what does it signify when we try to delete an event? In case the event is already deleted I am getting 410(Gone) and I understand that perfectly. I am using Google calendar API for android.

Comment: AFAIK, deleting event doesn't really delete the event but hide it. That is why there is a parameter "showDeleted"= true to include deleted events in your query. You can check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33340868/5995040) for reference. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors) error 409 means:

> The requested identifier already exists. An instance with the given ID
>   already exists in the storage.

Possible solution:

> Generate a new ID if you want to create a new instance, otherwise use
>   the update method call.

Comment: If the requested identifier exists, then why give error in case of delete?